# sed/awk merge pairs of lines into one line

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a list of data, in the following format:

```
Joined       : a
Whatever     : b
Last visited : c
Useful       : y
NotUseful1   : f
Email        : z
RandomWat    : g
*** end *** 
Joined       : a
Whatever     : b
Last visited : c
Useful       : y
NotUseful1   : f
Email        : z
RandomWat    : g
*** end ***
Joined       : h
Whatever     : i
Last visited : j
Useful       : k
NotUseful1   : l
Email        : m
RandomWat    : n
```

What I want is:

```
Useful, Email, Joined, Last Visited
y,z,a,c
y,z,a,c
k,m,h,j
```

I might've had a beer too many, but I can't work out how to get values across lines in fiex-length columns. Effectively a CSV format of some specific outputs.

Really I'm looking for something in sed/awk, though any text processor will do.

Comment: Are there multiple records? If so, how are they separated?

Comment: But your fields are separated by line breaks, no? A blank line?

Comment: Edited question to be a bit clearer.. hopefully..

Comment: Is it literally the text `*** end ***`?

Comment: To separate records? Yes.

Comment: Where did "Matt", etc. appear from in your expected output? Edit your question to make sure your expected output is precisely what you do expect given your posted sample input.

Comment: Is "fiex" supposed to be "fix", or "flex"?  I guess from the accept you want fixed-length, i.e. the same number of lines in each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set Awk's record separator to `**end**` and pick apart the fields with some light parsing; but if the format is a completely stable series of eight lines in a fixed order, all you really need is

```
awk -F ' *: *' -v OFS=, '{i=NR%8; a[i]=$NF }
    i==7 { print a[4], a[7], a[1], a[3] }' file
```

If your values could contain a colon, you will need to adapt -- this simple code just pulls out the stuff after the last colon.

Adding the CSV header left as an exercise (or just don't).

The `-F` option sets the input field separator, so Awk will split the line on colons, trimming any adjacent whitespace.  The `OFS` is the output field separator; we want the output comma-separated.  `NR` is the current input line number and `% 8` calculates the modulus; so the value of `i` goes from 1 to 7, then wraps to zero, and starts climbing again, repeating throughout the file.  Now, we use `i` as the index into an array `a` and collect the last field of each line into this array.  When we reach index 7, we have all the fields we need, so we print them. (I originally had this at 0 but then that would lose the last record, since you don't have a terminating `**end**` in your sample data.)

`NF` is the number of input fields and we expect this to be 2 basically all the time, so I could just as well have hard-coded `$2` there. If you need to extend this, I would completely forget about the `-F ' *: *'` and just manually `sub("^[^:]*: *", "")` and then have the entire value in `$0`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to print all of column 1 on one line and then the corresponding information from column two on the next line below it.

Using awk this is pretty simple.

```
awk '{ORS=" "} {print$1}' file.txt
awk '{ORS=" "} {print$NF}' file.txt
```

Output:

```
joined whatever last useful notuseful randomwat
a b c y f z g
```

`ORS` is Output record seperator. The default is a newline. But in this case we are making it a single space.

So for each line awk will print the first field of each line separated by a space.

Then we simply perform the same command but with the last field instead of the first. This will then print out the corresponding info on the next line with each record once again being separated by a space.

If you want your new columns to be a fixed width the I suggest using `printf` but I am sure there are other ways this can be done as well (I hear Perl is good at this).

`printf` suppresses newlines so we can remove the `ORS` part of awk.
However, since a newline won't ever be created we have to append an end  statement with a separate `printf` command after each awk command to get us to a new line, i.e.,

```
awk '{printf "%10s",$1}END{printf"\n"}' file.txt
awk '{printf "%10s",$NF}END{printf"\n"}' file.txt
```

This will print columns ten characters long for everything found with the awk statement.

Output:

```
joined  whatever       last    useful  notuseful     email randomwat
     a         b          c         y         f          z        g
```

*Note*: awk determines what each column is based on spaces. So in your example, "last visited" will only print out last since that is the first column. If you want multiple words to be grouped in a specific column, wrap the set of words in quotes `""`.

Comment: Update, If you need this to perform the same idea but for different sets of records (looks like you have three in your sample), use a grep or sed command to grab each record individually then pass it through to awk.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think awk is the best tool for the job, or I'm just unaware of some aspects of awk that would make this easier.

```
awk 'BEGIN{split("4,6,1,3",x,",");i=1;FS=":"}
    function s(e){gsub(/( *$)|(^ *)/,"",e);return e}
    function p(a){for(j=1;j<length(x);++j)printf "%s,",a[x[j]];print a[x[j]]}
    function e(){if(!d){p(h);d=1}p(v);i=1}
    {if(NF==1)e();else{if(!d)h[i]=s($1);v[i++]=s($2)}}
    END{e()}' infile.txt
```

It's not too elegant, but this eyesore does the job. You can also modify  `"4,6,1,3"` to select which fields to print in csv format.
For your example, this outputs the following:

```
Useful,Email,Joined,Last visited
y,z,a,c
y,z,a,c
k,m,h,j
```

This command requires that all entries have the same fields, keys and values are separated by `:`, and entries are separated by any line that does not contain a colon.

I know I'm late to the party, but I'd love to hear if you came up with a better solution to this problem.